# Why the variables are going out of scope in the for loop particularly while inside function

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, pycharm

I am expecting a list of dictionaries, but the dictionary depth is not known. It can be `list of dict of dict` or `list dict of dict of dict...`. But the output is coming in `unicode`. So I need to remove thee unicode and needs to change it `string`

```
json_result = [{u'NI': {u'Li': u'0', u'Receive': u'3', u'Slot': u'0002',u'PCID': u'165F', u'PCIV': u'14e4', u'LinkD': u'0','Per': u'44', u'Max': u'0', u'Pro':u'Br', u'Nic': u'3',u'Co': u'1.36', u'lis': [u'1',u'2']}}]

def abc(json_result):
    temp_res = [{}]
    for key, keyv1 in json_result.iteritems():
        if type(keyv1) is dict:
            temp_res[0][str(key)] = {}
            abc(keyv1)
            temp_res[0].update({key:keyv1})
        elif type(keyv1) is list:
            for i in xrange(len(keyv1)):
               keyv1[i] = str(keyv1[i])
               key = str(key)
        else:
            key = str(key)
            keyv1 = str(keyv1)

    return temp_res

ret = abc(json_result[0])
print ret
```

Output

```
[{'NI': {u'Slot': u'0002', u'Receive': u'3', u'lis': ['1', '2'], 'Per': u'44', u'Li': u'0', u'LinkD': u'0', u'PCIV': u'14e4', u'Co': u'1.36', u'Nic': u'3', u'Pro': u'Br', u'PCID': u'165F', u'Max': u'0'}}]
```

If you observe the output then First key `NI` has been converted into `string` and the `list` inside the `dict` also converted into the `string`. But others are not, why??
When I debugged the code, I can see that, it is changing to the `string` in `else`, but in final output it is not reflecting why?
And one more thing `pycharm` `shadows` the else part and tells that, local variables `key and keyv1` are not used.. Why?

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway? If you have non ascii characters using str is not going to end well, also as idjaw pointed toward you never actually use key or key1

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I think `recursion` is the only way to find out the `depth` of the dictionary. That is the reason why I followed this way. Please guide if you have any other ways to resolve the same,

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak, the recursion is fine if a bit overcomplicated, I would be more concerned about calling str on the unicode, what are you essentially trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where to start....

1) I'm not sure what you think `abc(keyv1)` does but `abc` has a return value you're ignoring so that's probably an issue. If you're trying to make `abc` an "in-place" function, don't. It just makes your code harder to read and understand.

2) In your else-if you're trying to change `keyv1`, `keyv1[i] = str(keyv1[i])`. Don't do that, create a new list and return in instead.

3) In your else clause you say `key = str(key)` but then you don't use `key` anywhere. You need to put `key` into your return structure.

4) Python dictionaries don't guarantee that the type of the key in the dictionary will be the same as the type of variable you used to update the dictionary. For example try this:

```
d = dict(one=1)
d[unicode('one')] = 'new value'
key = d.keys()[0]
print key, ':', type(key) # one : <type 'str'>
```

5) This isn't part of you question, but `str(unicode_thing)` does not always work, try this `str(u'abcdé')`. You either need to handle that exception explicitly or you must know a priori that `unicode_thing` is actually valid ascii. If the second is the case, then I would ask why are you using unicode at all?

Here is some code that might help you get started:

```
json_result = [{u'NI': {u'Li': u'0', u'Receive': u'3', u'Slot': u'0002',u'PCID': u'165F', u'PCIV': u'14e4', u'LinkD': u'0','Per': u'44', u'Max': u'0', u'Pro':u'Br', u'Nic': u'3',u'Co': u'1.36', u'lis': [u'1',u'2']}}]

def abc(item):
    if type(item) is list:
        return list(abc(i) for i in item)
    elif type(item) is dict:
        iteritem = item.iteritems()
        return dict((str(key), abc(value)) for (key, value) in iteritem)
    else:
        try:
            return str(item)
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            return item
            # Or maybe do something smarter.

print abc(json_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that when you recur, you throw away the result.  You have

abc(keyv1)

but you don't save the returned result anywhere.  You have to use this to alter the original dictionary.  Altering key and keyv1 doesn't do the trick; those are local variables.

The warning is correct: in that **else** clause, you set your local variables, return to the top of the loop, and then get new values for those variables, throwing away the string values you just had.  Again, you need to push these into the dictionary -- the temp_res values you're building.

I think these will help:

```
temp_res[0][str(key)] = abc(keyv1)
...
else:
    temp_res[0][str(key)] = str(keyv1)
```

Do you see how this works?

Output:

```
[{'NI': [{'Slot': '0002', 'PCIV': '14e4', 'Co': '1.36', 'Receive': '3', 'Nic': '3', 'Pro': 'Br', 'Per': '44', 'Li': '0', 'PCID': '165F', 'LinkD': '0', 'Max': '0'}]}]
```